When ever I run npm install comand, it is showing npm error 404 not found
I am using npm 11.0.0.
My environment variable is ok. I added the path.
I tried to install Nativescript bluetooth.
It is only showing npm error 404 not found,
I checked my environment variable, but it is ok.
What can I do, now? Is there any solution to fix this?

This question is similar to: Installing npm package fails with 404. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
